# imageresizer.net poor performance with simultaneous requests

Tags: imageresizer

I am trying out imageresizing.net, but found their performance to be really poor.  5 simultaneous request to resize 5 different large jpg on a 8 core machine, and the performance is like 5 second per image.

While a single request to resize for the same image is 1.1 second.

This is on a clean Win 2008 r2 server, on a separate new asp.net site running .net 4 in integrated mode, and the imageresizing library running as HTTP Module.

I can't validate the claimed performance and scale from their web site.

Can someone share their experience with using imageresizing.net, is the kind of performance I measured is normal?  It seems that the library cannot resize multiple images at the same time, and rely on the disk cache to gain performance on subsequent request of the same image.  My scenario is that re sizing of images will most likely not be repeated, ie won't have cache hit, hence raw performance is important.

Comment: Could you provide the Jpeg files and/or the byte size and resolution? It's not the right tool for gigapixel images.

Comment: We're tracking a GDI+ performance issue related to a recent windows update. It does not affect the [WIC pipeline](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/wic), so you might want to give that a try to see if it might be related.

Comment: Also, enabling the IIS web garden feature has shown to eliminate the problem.